# initWithString of CCLabelBMFont COCOS2D class throws NSInternalInconsistencyException exception

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

Instancing CCLabelBMFont this way

```
   _targetDistanceBM =[[CCLabelBMFont alloc] initWithString:@"" fntFile:@"font.fnt"]
```

causes exception "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'TextureCache: fileimage MUST not be nil'"

According to many posts this seems to be the way to created it.

Font file was created with online tool [littera](http://kvazars.com/littera/).

I'm using COCOS2D version 3, that comes with COCOS3D.

Answer (score 0):

COCO2D only support text format fnt files. Also, the corresponding png file must be placed in the same folder then the fnt file.